# Parse Complex Json Java Mulit-nodes

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a complex JSON with multi nodes:

```
{
  "List": {
    "Summary": {
      "0": {
        "Id": 163375,
        "city" : "Paris"

    },
      "1": {
        "Id": 15541,
        "city" : "London"

    },
      "2": {
        "Id": 18459,
        "city" : "Berlin"

    }
   }
  }
}
```

I need Id and City for each node 0,1, 2...

1. How I can parse the information I want? (third node...).
2. How I can iterate? (sometime, I can have 25 or more nodes I mean 0 until 25).

Thank in advance for your help!

P.

Comment: You are right, just edited the right JSON. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  Jackson for that and its `JsonNode`:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final JsonNode input = mapper.readTree(yourSourceHere);

Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry;

final Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator
    = input.get("List").get("Summary").fields();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    entry = iterator.next();
    // work with entry
}
```

NOTE however: object member order is NOT significant in JSON (see RFC 4627). It is strange that the internal objects are not stored in an array instead (since array element order *is* significant).

That is: `{"0": null, "1": null}` and `{"1": null, "0": null}` are the same object, but `[0, 1]` and `[1, 0]` are not the same array.

Jackson will read in the order of appearance, but that's an "accident". Do NOT rely on it.

Comment: Thanks!Actually this is the JSON structure of Expedia API.

Comment: Heh, you should point the problem to them ;) Have a link to the docs?

Comment: Btw thanks for the code. For final Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator = input.get("List").get("Summary"); I have a problem of cast "cannot convert from JsonNode to Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>>"

Comment: I've fixed the code, it was missing a `.fields()` at the end

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it. Just a last question, how I can get the String with the entry? Thanks

Comment: `entry.getValue().stringValue()` will return it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
org.json.JSONObject json = new JSONObject("Place your JSON here");
json = json.getJSONObject("List").getJSONObject("Summary").getJSONObject("2");
System.out.println(json.toString());
```

This only works if you know what ID your required Object has.

Maven Dependency for JSONObject:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20140107</version>
</dependency>
```